# How to display the latest called object on top?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a custom select plugin. Everything is going great, but the dropdowns (`<ul>`-objects) are overlapping on each other :(

I understand, that the overlapping order is set after the elements order on page or when they are created. So my question is: **What is the method to make the latest opened/shown object (`<ul>`) on top of the hierarchy?**

I just need the correct method. I'm not going to copy the full code, but a little example:

```
$('#trigger').click(function () {
    new_dropdown.slideDown();
});
```

*(A picture is worth of 1000 words)*

[image]

So lets say, that I open the green select the last.. How can I make it on top of the yellow one?

**EDIT**

For easier testing I created jsfiddle. For future references I'll post the link: **http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/uZV5p/1/** This is the live demo of the problem at hand.

Comment: Do you need them both to be visible/open at the same time? Wouldn't it be easier if one closes, when the other is opened?

Comment: From a user perspective I would definitely go with David Thomas' suggestion. However, if you must you will need to have position: relative or absolute and use z-index's to display them in the correct order

Comment: Yes, and also if possible then the green select to open up and not down. Also it closes others, when another one gets opened. But I want to have the feature, to open multiple ones. For that I need to solve this issue.

Comment: @James Hay: You are absolutely correct. But I need multiple-opened-selects feature for the goal-project. In that project, they will be aligned next to each other and not on top.. But this issue will still be a drawback of the script in my eyes. Would something similar work `new_dropdown.css(z-index, 100).slideDown();`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [CSS z-index property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) (higher values put elements at the front).

You could probably just set them in ascending order (e.g. set green one to 1000, yellow to 1001), but if you really need to bring it to the front when clicked, you can change the z-index with javascript

```
var zindex=100;

$("#trigger").click( function() {
    newdropdown.css('z-index', ++zindex);
});
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/waitinforatrain/Vf7Hu/ (click the red and blue divs to bring to front).

Edit: gilly3's approach is better, and as was mentioned there may be some issues with older versions of IE.

Comment: Note that the maximum value z-index can get to is ~2 billion. I presume that won't be a problem :p

Comment: Very nice demonstration btw. And I also like the ++zindex idea. Definitely worth of +1.

Comment: Yours could stack three on top of each other and still keep them in the right order if one was dismissed. So I think your answer is better. (Upvoting it BTW.)

Comment: I had some issues with your provided method, but I felt it was because of my own messy code. So I created a independent testing-grouns: http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/uZV5p/2/ Everything seems to work perfectly.

Comment: @Kalle Glad to help, be sure to test it in IE

Comment: @waitinforatrain: Works down to ie6 (jsfiddle doesn't support ie5.5 lol.) Basically, this is the best solution and answer. Thanks alot. Its having some conflicts with my own code atm, but since I know this method works, then I will find the issue shortly.. :P Thanks again, I might have come up with the z-index my own, but the dynamic zindex=100 is just brilliant!

Comment: For future references: My problem was, that when the plugin was set to 3 different selects. Then each time the zindex was 100. So I made a global variable: `$.fn.DropDownSelect_zindex = 100;` before the plugin. Works ^^

Answer (score 2):

Two ways:

**Set a z-index**

Setting a z-index will change the default stacking order. You can have a counter that increments and use that to set the z-index of newly stacked items. You may have issues with IE 7 or earlier, though, and those can be fixed by setting the z-index of other items. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Understanding_CSS_z-index/Adding_z-index

**Use absolute positioning, and append the div to the body**

If you use absolute positioning, you can append the div to the body and still have it appear below the element. If you append the div to the body, the one last added should be on top, because of the default stacking order.

Comment: Absolute positioning is in use already, as you can see their placement. And thats probably where the issue is coming from. Thanks for bringing that to my attention. +1

Comment: Sure thing. I could have worded that differently. To me absolute positioning on a child of the body is more absolute than absolute positioning on a nested element.

Answer (score 2):

Give it a class when it is opened, and remove that class from the previously opened ones:

```
$(".slidedown_active").removeClass("slidedown_active");
$(this).addClass(".slidedown_active");
```

Then your users can use `z-index` in their style definition for that class to ensure the active list is always visible.

The reason I don't recommend setting the `z-index` directly is because you can mess up your users' layout unnecessarily.  These kind of overlap issues can be a real headache for a web developer.  For a plugin to try to guess at how to resolve overlap issues, without any knowledge of the code or design, would be virtually impossible.  Instead, give your users the tools they need to fix the overlap issues themselves.  It may be that your users would never encounter overlap issues, so setting the z-index for them would be pointless at best, and potentially harmful.

Comment: Very interesting idea. I'm going to test this and z-index. And run them trough different versions of different browsers. Thanks.

Comment: Is this what you meant? http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/uZV5p/2/ It seems not to work, I might have gotten something wrong of course.

Comment: Nope.  Maybe this comment missed it's intended target, because that jsfiddle doesn't do anything with classes.